# Get the ID of polygon in edition sessions of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, qt4

I did a Qt custom form for QGIS which contain a QlineEdit that must get the ID of the current polygon in edit session.

For example, I start edit sessions I draw 3 polygons when the Qt form is opened the QLineEdit is empty so only when I save modification and then when I click on my polygons I get the ID.

PS: I tried signals of QGIS but that doesn't work on QGIS 1.8.
Could someone help me please !!

Comment: could you please spend some time to format/punctuate the question?

Comment: i tryed sorry for the level of english !

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Feature IDs are not generated until the feature is saved because the provider will allocate the new ID.  It's not up to QGIS what the next one is.

If you are using shapefiles. or you know what the next id is going to be, you can set it yourself using:

```
feature.setFeatureId(yourid)
```

However I wouldn't recommend this as the provider might change it on you once you save.